# detailed explanation of a sherical gyroid code and how to modify the code to obtain different pores sizes and numbers

Tags: graphics3d, 3d-printing, editing

***I have the code of a spherical gyroid below which I have used to print a 3D object sphere. i will need a detailed explanation of all the terms starting from a = 3 pi till mesh. moreover i printed the 3D onject and had the below object, which parameters can i edit to have so many pore sizes. The code is given below:

```
a = 3 \[Pi];
mesh = BoundaryDiscretizeRegion[
    ImplicitRegion[
     Sin[x] Cos[y] + Sin[y] Cos[z] + Sin[z] Cos[x] < 0 && 
      x^2 + y^2 + z^2 < a^2, {{x, -a, a}, {y, -a, a}, {z, -a, a}}], 
    MaxCellMeasure -> .1/10]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

mesh***
[image]

Comment: You get more pores by increasing the 'frequency' of the trig functions, e.g by a factor of 2: `Sin[2 x] Cos[2 y] + Sin[2 y] Cos[2 z] + Sin[2 z] Cos[2 x] < 0`

Comment: thank you sir for the answer. I will like you to explain to me in detail what each word means in the code

Comment: Have you tried looking at the documentation for each of the symbols in the expression?

Comment: Good afternoon sir, I have not looked at any documentation. I will be grateful if you recommend me to a document i can use